# WPF Storyboard with images, start board when it's visible

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm pretty new to WPF and trying out some stuff with a storyboard, what I want to do is start the storyboard when it is visible for the first time.. (since it's a step in a wizard that isn't visible at load)

```
 <Grid Name="GridLoading" Visibility="Hidden" >

        <Image>
            <Image.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">

                    <BeginStoryboard >
                        <Storyboard Name="LoadingStoryBoard" Completed="LoadingStoryBoard_Completed">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source"
                                               Duration="0:0:4">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\...\2a-loading.jpg"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\...\2b-loading.jpg"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\...\2c-loading.jpg"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\...\2d-loading.jpg"/>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Image.Triggers>
        </Image>

    </Grid>
```

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a duplicate of: [Activate Storyboard on Visibility Changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397819/activate-storyboard-on-visibility-changed)

Taken from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22398068/7604843) in that question:

```
<Style x:Key="AnimationImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=IsVisible}" 
                 Value="True">

        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="1.0" To="0.1"
                                     Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                     AutoReverse="True"
                                     RepeatBehavior="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Replace the storyboard inside `<DataTrigger.EnterActions>` with your storyboard.

Question to more experienced users:  How do I mark a post as duplicate?  Or is that for mods only?

Comment: Thanks! Only thing I need to figure out now is to perform some code when the animation is finished since Completed="LoadingStoryBoard_Completed" seems to be invalid if it's inside a style element